# How to store old(previous) location of location manager

Tags: android, android-location

I found android location method distanceBetween() to measure the distance. It requires to pass the old(previous) location (Lon Lat) and new location. I am confused how to store the old location if the location is getting updated every 5s and eventually im getting back distance = 0.0

Thanks for any help

Comment: Once you get the new location, store it at some place (SharedPreferences maybe). Now when you get the updates location, fetch the old location and pass it to `distanceBetween`. After that, replace the old location with this new received one.

Comment: Just create a class variable `Location` object and do the calculation with it and initialize it with the new location once you've completed the calc